# OpenCV 4.5.5: How to fit line to sequence of points to create vector that preserves original point order

Tags: python, opencv, linear-algebra

I am using OpenCV (4.5.5) in Python 3.10.4 to open a scanned image of a calibration plate that is at an arbitrary rotation and orient the plate based on user input.

The plates look like this:
[image: calibration plate]

I find contours and `minEnclosingCircle` to find center points for all the calibration dots and then display the image and have the user click the center dot and then any number of dots in the +X direction.  Code matches a click to a found calibration dot and appends the corresponding x,y to an array.

Example:
[image: rotated]

When I pass the points to `cv2.fitLine` and calculate the angle, it returns 30 degrees instead of the expected -150 degrees.

```
vx, vy, x0, y0 = cv2.fitLine(np.float32(clicks), cv2.DIST_L2, 0, .1, .1)
x_axis = [1, 0]
found_line = np.array([vx, vy])
dot_prod = np.dot(x_axis, found_line)
angle_x = np.degrees(np.arccos(dot_prod))
print(angle_x)

:[30]

#looking at just the first two clicked points
clicked_line = np.array(clicks[1]) - np.array(clicks[0])
angle_x = np.math.atan2(np.linalg.det([clicked_line, x_axis]), np.dot(clicked_line, x_axis))
print(np.degrees(angle_x)

:-150
```

I re-ran the point-selecting and line fitting code after rotating it based on second method and the best fit line was ~0.4 degrees from the x-axis which is pretty good but it would be nice to have the extra accuracy available from selecting multiple points.

Thanks!

Comment: -30 degrees are equivalent to 150 degrees, given a line has no direction. -- there is no opencv "3.5"-anything. -- opencv also doesn't appear to have algorithms that put a *set of points* representing a grid _into_ any order. there are functions to detect a "circles grid". they may work here, if all points can be recognized and you know the number of points. -- the calibration patterns you present look proprietary to me.

Comment: I recognize the angles are complimentary, however, if I tell the computer to rotate the image -30 degrees, I end up with an upside down image.  I was hoping by selecting the points in a specific order, I could provide directionality. The overall shape/size of the calibration plate can very but the dot size and spacing is generally consistent.  I hadn't come across findCirclesGrid, I'll take a closer look but it looks like it requires more consistency than what I have.

Comment: if you can at least locate all the points, that'd be a start. -- I was toying with some ad-hoc approach that assembles a grid from a point set using nearest neighbor queries and some assumptions (triangle/hex or square grid). it was idle toying though, not done.

Comment: I have the contour stored for each dot so when the user clicks on a dot, I iterate all the contours and use `pointPolygonTest` to see if the click is inside one of the contours, if it is, I use `minEnclosingCircle` to return the centroid(x, y) and radius. That centroid is what I store and then later want to find the best fit line to determine which angle to rotate the image at.

Comment: What about making this code interactive, watch what it outputs and adjust accordingly/understand what's going on etc. Add keys to rotate it with some angles left/right and see how it changes, write a sequence that displays the numbers of the points, e.g. overlays another circle on the next/previous in the array and choose the current by pressing keys, and the color of that overlay circle could be a gradient so that you can see the layout of the points. Etc. Also Re accuracy, is it achievable from the points only given their scale in the image. Maybe a sub-pixel method is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up doing. I'm sure there is a cleaner way but this way seems to work:

I prompt the user to select the center point and then several points to the right of it (+x).  I then use the methods in my question to calculate a fine angle (first method) and a rough angle (second method).  Since the rough angle  is in the proper quadrant, I use that as a test to see how to manipulate the fine angle to be in the same quadrant.

```
if angle_x_rough < 0 and angle_x_rough >= -90:
    angle_x = -angle_x_fine
elif angle_x_rough < -90 and angle_x_rough <= -180:
    angle_x = angle_x_fine - 180
elif angle_x_rough > 0 and angle_x_rough <=90:
    angle_x = angle_x_fine
elif angle_x_rough > 90 and angle_x_rough <=180:
    angle_x = 180 - angle_x_fine
```